# Error of internal error in value_from_output_section when using cross-compilation with NDK in Android studio

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I am working on an Android Studio project by using NDK and cmake.
When I build it up, I got an error called "internal error in value_from_output_section".

```
  [207/208] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libToyDisplay.so
  FAILED: ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libToyDisplay.so 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\18.1.5063045\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -Oz -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -LC:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libToyDisplay.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libToyDisplay.so CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Base.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/ConfigFile.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/d3dLoadEntity.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/d3dSceneAct.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/d3dScense.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/d3dSeceneWeb.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/GlobalInterface.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/GUI_API/gui_globe.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/GUI_API/gui_Ime.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/GUI_API/gui_List.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/GUI_API/gui_Text.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/OgreFramework.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/OgreFrameworkObjects.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/RectLayoutManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/GlobalDataAndroid/ToyGlobalInterface.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/ToyMove.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/ToyMoveFSM.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/ToyMoveState.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/ToyMoveStateJump.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/ToyMoveStateSlip.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/ToyMoveStateSwim.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/ToyMoveStateWalk.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ToyDisplay.dir/Source/Toy/Display/ToyUI.cpp.o  -Wl,--start-group -landroid ../../../../src/main/Run-Sup/ogre_android1.12.8/build/lib/libcpufeatures.a ../../../../src/main/Run-Sup/ogre_android1.12.8/build/lib/libzziplib.a ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libToyD3D.so ../../../../src/main/Run-Sup/ogre_android1.12.8/build/lib/libOgreMainStatic.a ../../../../src/main/Run-Sup/ogre_android1.12.8/build/lib/libOgreOverlayStatic.a ../../../../src/main/Run-Sup/ogre_android1.12.8/build/lib/libfreetype.a -Wl,--end-group ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libToyMath.so -lm ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libMiniZip.so -llog -lz -latomic -lm "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++_static.a" "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++abi.a" "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libandroid_support.a" "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libunwind.a" "-ldl" && cd ."
  C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: internal error in value_from_output_section, at /buildbot/src/android/binutils/toolchain/binutils/binutils-2.27/gold/reloc.cc:1495
  clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have try to change NDK version from 16 to 18, but both of them got same error in ToolBar "Build Output". But there is another error shows in Event Log. Maybe these two errors have some connections.
I'm not sure.

```
11:02   C/C++ Configuration Problem
        MiniZip | debug | armeabi-v7a
            Compiler exited with error code 1: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\18.1.5063045\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe -xc -isystem C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Oz -DNDEBUG -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
            Android (4751641 based on r328903) clang version 7.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 003100370607242ddd5815e4a043907ea9004281) (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm 1d739ffb0366421d383e04ff80ec2ee591315116) (based on LLVM 7.0.2svn)
            Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
            Thread model: posix
            InstalledDir: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\18.1.5063045\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
            clang.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfloat-abi=softfp' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] clang.exe: 
            warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] clang.exe: 
            warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mthumb' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] clang.exe: 
            warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Wa,--noexecstack' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\18.1.5063045\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\bin\\clang.exe" 
            -cc1 -triple x86_64-w64-windows-gnu -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name
            compiler-file1449694187694939204 -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -fmath-errno -masm-verbose
            -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu armv7-a -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4
            -debugger-tuning=gdb -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -ffunction-sections 
            -resource-dir       "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\18.1.5063045\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\lib64\\clang\\7.0.2" 
            -isystem C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D ANDROID -D NDEBUG -D ___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END 
            -internal-isystem "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\18.1.5063045\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\lib64\\clang\\7.0.2\\include" 
            -internal-isystem "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\18.1.5063045\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include" 
            -internal-isystem "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\18.1.5063045\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include" 
            -internal-isystem "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\18.1.5063045\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\include" -Oz -Wformat -fdebug-compilation-dir "D:\\ogre\\Android_Studio_Proj\\IQI-ogre1.12.8\\app\\.externalNativeBuild\\cmake\\debug\\armeabi-v7a" 
            -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 2 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fseh-exceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -vectorize-slp -dD -o - -x c 
            "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\compiler-file1449694187694939204" 
            error: unknown target CPU 'armv7-a' note: valid target CPU values are: nocona, core2, penryn, bonnell, atom, silvermont, slm, goldmont, nehalem, corei7, westmere, sandybridge, corei7-avx, ivybridge, core-avx-i, haswell, core-avx2, broadwell, skylake, skylake-avx512, skx, cannonlake, icelake, knl, knm, k8, athlon64, athlon-fx, opteron, k8-sse3, athlon64-sse3, opteron-sse3, amdfam10, barcelona, btver1, btver2, bdver1, bdver2, bdver3, bdver4, znver1, x86-64
```

Is anyone get some iders? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Congratulations! you broke the compiler. You should probably upgrade your NDK to a non-ancient version (r21) where this bug is fixed.

Comment: wow, it sounds not good. :( Thanks for reply. I will try that!

Comment: Unfortunately, the error still there when I built it with NDK r21.

Comment: Then you need to file a bug with Android; that should not happen.

Comment: Finally, I followed the advice in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173730333. Then it works.